# Displaying a PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, embed

I tried using this in my asp page as i found this on stack overflow, but when i run the application it doesn't do anything, the problem is in the pdfLocation() mine is returning a string value that is the path to the pdf file. is this correct

```
<embed id="Embed1" src='<%# pdfLocation() %>' runat="server" name="pdfLoad"/>
```

this is the function

```
public string pdfLocation()
{
   return "pdf/2.pdf";
}
```

Comment: what is acutally your question can you explain does pdfLocation() run? have you added breakpoint

Comment: the function never runs, should i put code in the page load function or is there some javascript i can add

Comment: Do you want to display pdf there are other alternatives . I dont know why your function never runs but there is nothing wrong with your code maybe you are using embed tag try anchor tag and let me know

Comment: well yes please. when i put the address directly into the embed statement it works though

Comment: use orangebox to show pdf visit http://davidpaulhamilton.net/orangebox/examples/ 
let me know if this helps

Comment: read this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20699/Embed-PDFs-into-a-Web-Page-with-a-Custom-Control dont use embed tag its not working

Comment: http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/